# Asp.net Master.Page file in different directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008

I have a Website on our Server that controls many different little applications, each in its own directory.

```
Default.aspx
Master.Page
web.config
app1/Default.aspx
app2/Default.aspx
app3/Default.aspx
```

Each of these other little applications has the master page set in the ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Page" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="server1.app1.Default" %>
```

This works fine when I am running the application on my PC's localhost, but the server can't seem to figure it out when I publish it.

I also tried to specify the Master Page using the Web.Config file (located in the root):

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="AutoID" masterPageFile="~/Master.Page" />
</system.web>
```

This still works on `localhost`, but not on the server.

How do I resolve this?

**UPDATE:**

Adding App Pool screenshot.

[image: app pool]

**UPDATE 2:**

Publishing method.

[image: publish]

Comment: Do you have your own separate app pool?

Comment: Yes! Is that what is causing my problem? Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Each application would have its own root.  They may be looking one directory below where you want them to look.  Also, is this a precompiled site or are you just copying the code and aspx files to the server?

Comment: @jp2code can you show the master page contents and the associated code-behind?

Comment: @ps2goat: Currently, I'm using FTP in Visual Studio, but that's only because I don't know the best way to publish my files up. Should I use something else?

Comment: @Rex: My supervisor is one of those who thinks the Internet is going to get him. He has told me not to publish anything identifiable online, and there are many snippets of code in the master page that link to databases and such. By the time I hacked it to be displayable, I fear it would be full of errors.

Comment: @jp2code just post the page directive, the top line in your master page. Also try to publish the release copy of the app and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: When you look at the server, are there both `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` files?